# Optimizing setting of pixels in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pixel-manipulation

The HTML5 Canvas has no method for explicitly setting a single pixel.

The solution I know so far is :

- use `getImageData` and `putImageData` but the efficiency is too low for animation
  due to the low performance of `putImageData`
- use heavy object like `rect` or `putImageData` to draw single pixel  but the performance seems far worse when there is a lot of pixel to draw.

I have seen that the `drawImage` function is really faster than the `putImageData`
and indeed if we replace `putImageData` by `drawImage(new Image(w,h))`, it is really fast. 
However i do not know any solution to put an image on argument of `drawImage` which can be set pixel by pixel fastly.

Her is an example of slow code

HTML:

```
<canvas id="graph1" width="1900" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
    var canvas=document.getElementById("graph1"),
        ctx=canvas.getContext("2d"),
        imageData,
        data,
        w=canvas.width,
        loop=0,
        t=Date.now();

    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
      })();


    function animate() {
        imageData=ctx.createImageData(w, canvas.height);
        data=imageData.data;
        for(i=0;i<30000;i++) { // Loop fast enough
            x=Math.round(w*Math.random());
            y=Math.round(canvas.height*Math.random());   
            data[((w * y) + x) * 4]=255;
            data[((w * y) + x) * 4+1]=0;
            data[((w * y) + x) * 4+2]=0;
            data[((w * y) + x) * 4+3]=255;
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0); //Slow
        //ctx.drawImage(new Image(canvas.width, canvas.height),0,0);// Would be about 4x faster even if ImageData would be also blank

        requestAnimFrame(function() {
                loop++;
                if(loop<100)
                    animate();
                else
                    alert('finish:'+(Date.now()-t));
            });
    }
    animate();
```

If someone have a clue to improve performance.

Comment: Did you try putting pixels with a fillRect (x,y,1,1 ) ??

Comment: The browsers might have evolved since I writted this message, but at the time I tested to use rect object and it was far worst than any solution.

Answer (score 0):

`putImageData` is what you will want to use, (if you are planning on html5 canvas).  It is just as fast as `drawImage`.

If both `drawImage` and `putImageData` methods have similar images that they repaint, they end up being the same speed.  You are comparing repainting speeds of completely random pixes, to repainting of blank over and over.  If you need proof of this I can make an example.

Comment: I am not sure of that at all. You can have a look at http://jsperf.com/buffering . `drawImage` is about 100x faster than `putImageData`. And on my sample replace the line `ctx.putImageData(...)` by the line `ctx.drawImage(...)` and you will see that the script is faster even for a blank image (only 4 times faster on this example but it will be nice enough to improve fluency of animation). It is indeed very strange by the way that the browsers are optimized for `drawImage` and not for `putImageData`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DEw3b/1/ It's interesting that this is equal on one of my computers but not on another.  In any case, you can't do single pixels with draw.  So it's sort of a not that important.